# kubectl diff on windows returns an error: executable file not found in PATH

Tags: windows, kubernetes, docker-desktop

I have a problem using Kubectl on Windows:

```
C:\> kubectl diff -f app.yml
error: executable file not found in %PATH%
```

Kubernetes is installed with the Docker Desktop. The same error comes independent of the file, I'm using as an argument (even if the .yml file doesn't contain anything).

Version:

```
C:\> kubectl version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"16", GitVersion:"v1.16.0", GitCommit:"2bd9643cee5b3b3a5ecbd3af49d09018f0773c77", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2019-09-18T14:36:53Z", GoVersion:"go1.12.9", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"windows/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"14", GitVersion:"v1.14.6", GitCommit:"96fac5cd13a5dc064f7d9f4f23030a6aeface6cc", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2019-08-19T11:05:16Z", GoVersion:"go1.12.9", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

Comment: Could you please check if your system PATH environment variable for `kubectl` is set correctly at `Advanced System Settings -> Advanced -> Environment Variables -> Path`?

Comment: Yes, it set correctly. The error comes even if I explicitly call the kubectl.exe from its folder.
But the error seems not to be a Windows-path error. It looks like an Unix-error inside the Docker.

Comment: I agree, we can do better. I opened an issue: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/87343

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After installing [DiffUtils for Windows](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/diffutils.htm) on my local machine and restarting the machine everything works.

Answer (score 7):

Try to install using choco - no need to restart Windows.

```
choco install diffutils
```

Answer (score 4):

The `kubectl diff` command uses the Unix `diff` program under the hood. Presumably you don't have this installed. You can probably install it through WSL or your other favorite way to get Unix-y programs.

Comment: It could be so, but the k8s is running under Docker Desktop and if the problem is there, I don't know how to tell Docker to install the diff.

Comment: It’s not a server side thing, kubectl itself is trying to run diff.

Comment: @OhHiMark Yes, I've installed `diffutils` and now it works

Answer (score 2):

Having had essentially the same issue as OP the solution for me required some extra steps: installing [DiffUtils for Windows](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/diffutils.htm) as mentioned, and then mapping the bin folder (by default at `C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\bin`) in my Win10 PATH variable.

I'm assuming the installer for DiffUtils was supposed to map it, but for whatever reason it failed to do so, resulting in me having to do this manually.

Answer (score 1):

If you already have a preferred diff tool installed, set $Env:KUBECTL_EXTERNAL_DIFF. For example:

```
$Env:KUBECTL_EXTERNAL_DIFF="C:\Progra~1\WinMerge\WinMergeU.exe"
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error. I had **git bash** installed on my Windows 10 machine. So tried and it worked.
So as @coderanger mentioned, it uses UNIX diff program under the hood, git bash works